# C++ unknown error/bug in program flow

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

I am just reviewing C++ and I don't know why 3 and 5 are the only working option. I already converted it to if-else statement but still the same issue. Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c, s[50] = {'\0'};
    int num;

    cout << "Select cin method:" << endl;
    cout << "1. cin.get(c);" << endl;
    cout << "2. cin.get(s, 10);" << endl;
    cout << "3. cin.get(s, 10, '*');" << endl;
    cout << "4. cin.getline(s, 10);" << endl;
    cout << "5. cin.read(s, 10);" << endl;
    cout << "Select: " << flush;
    cin >> num;

    switch (num) {
        case 1:
            cin.get(c); //  cin >> c;
            break;
        case 2:
            cin.get(s, 10); //  cin >> s; max length 10, '\n' as string terminator
            break;
        case 3:
            cin.get(s, 10, '*');    //  cin >> s; max length 10, '*' as string terminator
            break;
        case 4:
            cin.getline(s, 10);     //  cin >> s; max length 10, '\n' as string terminator
            break;
        case 5:
            cin.read(s, 10);        //  cin >> s; max length 10, records '\n'
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (num == 1)
        cout.put(c);                //  cout << s;
    if (num >= 2 && num <= 5)
        cout.write(s, 15);          //  cout << s; max length 15
}
```

Whenever I input 1/2/4 for num, it just bypasses the switch and else-if statements. I already tried checking what num is getting by "cout << num" and the value it gets is correct. I don't receive any error message either. Below is the sample of what I am getting:

```
Select cin method: 
1. cin.get(c); 
2. cin.get(s, 10); 
3. cin.get(s, 10, '*'); 
4. cin.getline(s, 10); 
5. cin.read(s, 10); 
Select: 1 
-------------------------------- 
Process exited after 1.676 seconds with return value 0 Press any key to continue
```

Comment: Please describe how #1, 2, and 4 are not working. What behavior or error message did you get? What were you expecting to see?

Comment: It's just a review about cin methods. Whenever I input 1/2/4 for num, it just bypasses the switch and else-if statements. I already tried checking what num is getting by "cout << num" and the value it gets is correct. 

I don't receive any error message either.

Below is the sample of what I am getting:

Select cin method:
1. cin.get(c);
2. cin.get(s, 10);
3. cin.get(s, 10, '*');
4. cin.getline(s, 10);
5. cin.read(s, 10);
Select: 1


--------------------------------
Process exited after 1.676 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: You can't see white characters in print. Try surrounding the `c` and `s` value with some braces or quotation marks when printing them out...

Comment: Note that after the first input (`num`), you probably press the "enter" key which appends a `\n` to the input stream which is what will be read by `cin.get` and `cin.getline` (the default delimiter version).

Comment: @CiaPan: Whenever I select 1/2/4, it doesn't even asks me for num. It bypasses "cin >> num" and the switch/if-else statements.

Comment: By stepping through in a debugger or adding debug output statements, you would easily see the switch is not bypassed and that `s` gets a new value, just like 3 and 5.

Comment: It obviously does not "bypass the switch and else-if statements". Concentrate on figuring out what `cin` is doing. You could have entirely abstracted away the switch and figured out a small reproducing example of asking the user for a number then doing `cin.get(c)`. Then you'll find that there are a ton of duplicates of the question, with your answer!

Comment: This might be the most comprehensive such answer I've come across: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: @chris: Oh thanks. I still don't know how to run the debugger. But all of you are right, it does not bypass the statements. I tried putting an output in one of the condition and it shows.

Comment: Whenever you select 1/2/4, it doesn't even asks you for num... because your selection (1 or 2 or 4) was input into `num`! And then the code is executed which either inputs a single character (case 1) or a string (case 2) or a line (case 3). Case 1 inputs a newline char which terminates your `num` input, other two cases read an empty string terminated by that newline. I told you to surround `cout` output with some additional characters, then you would have noticed they get split into two lines by a newline character printed from `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't bypass the `switch`, it executes it correctly. The problems is that, after reading the number, the input stream has an extra character in it (the `\n` you press after the number) and that causes the behavior you're seeing for cases 1, 2 and 4. The next read operation you're doing in those cases finds that `\n` and stop reading.

To fix it you can add something like this after the `cin >> num`:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

(and include `<limits>`

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! This worked. I haven't seen this code before. I am now wondering how cin really works.

Comment: Well, it works as one might expect from a stream: you advance in the stream by reading stuff from it. The idea is that you should know what the stream contains. In your case, if you type "1<ENTER>" on your keyboard, the stream will contain `1\n`. `cin >> num` reads only the `1`, so the next read from the stream will start with the `\n`. What that line of code does is to basically clear the rest of the stream, so the next read operation starts clean.

Comment: Oh I get it. I also tried to change 'cin.get(c)' to 'cin >> c' and it worked. Now I already know additional information about the difference of 'cin' from 'cin.get()' and about istream. Thanks.